# Change IntelliJ "Make" Behavior

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to change IntelliJ's default "Make" Behavior? Whatever its doing, its wrong and causing build issues. I would like to set it to use a specific SBT task.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an "SBT Tool Window" when working with these type of Scala projects (if it is set up correctly). The IntelliJ documentation has some detailed info/screenshots: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+SBT

The `Build > Make Project` does a literal compile of the source code, so I guess you could consider it a very small subset of what you would do in SBT/Maven/Ant etc.